# Fetch Number of Rows in a SQLite3 query

Tags: php, sqlite

Can someone explain how SQLite3 is used to give the number of rows found in a query?

mysql has `mysql_num_rows` and SQLite2 has a similar function but someone in SQLite3 development seems to have forgotten to add that function.

The examples that I have seen here and on other sites do not answer the question but instead only create more questions.

I have a query like `$queryStr = $d->query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE uid='{$userid}' AND account='active';");`

what I want to know is how do I find out how many results are in `$queryStr`.

I am not looking for the number of rows in the database, just the number of rows in the query results.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite computes query results on the fly (because this is more efficient for an embedded database where there is no network communication).

Therefore, it is not possible to find out how many records a query returns without actually stepping through all those records.

You should, if at all possible, structure your algorithm so that you do not need to know the number of records before you have read them.
Otherwise, you have to execute a separate query that uses `SELECT COUNT(*)` to return the number of records, like this:

```
$countQuery = $d->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitors WHERE uid='{$userid}' AND account='active';");
```

Comment: I have seen that response to other posts and it does not answer the question, HOW do you get the number of rows in a query result, it is odd to say that the number of results is unknown given a query has pulled all those results for you. It is not a very good way of finding numbers of results when you have to run the same query twice.

Comment: The question still remains how to you use the SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... and what exactly is ... ?

Comment: The query has *not* yet pulled the records; each record is pulled individually with `fetchArray`.

Comment: Ok, I tried that... I get an error message

Notice: Object of class SQLite3Result could not be converted to int in H:\Program Files\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\dologin.php on line 15

and line 15 is...

$numRows = (int)($d->query( sprintf($queryString,"COUNT(*)",$u,$p) ) );

and the $queryString is $queryString = "SELECT %s FROM visitors WHERE uid='%s' AND account='active';--";

So I am scratching my head because without the cast (int) the error is the same.

Comment: The `COUNT(*)` query is a normal query which you must handle like any other query; the only difference is that you get back a single row with a single column.

Comment: I have tried and all I get is an error message about not being able to convert to string or other error messages. Considering SQLite2 had a function specifically to return this information, it seems to me utterly stupid to not be able to get a count as part of the query results. The query is exactly as shown or advised and I see no reason for this problem to exist, I can put stuff in, retrieve it, delete it, merge it sellotape it, sharpie it but not count the effing results... I ask you, what complete melon head decided at SQLite that it was the way to go?